Why am I experiencing Wi-Fi connection issues on a MacBook Air M3?
I have a brand new MacBook Air M3 (13.6"). I'm on latest version of macOS 15 (Sequoia).
Sometimes I've noticed that the Wi-Fi connection will go down and after a while it will try to reconnect. I'm not sure if this is a bug of Apple or if the problem is with the machine.
I've tried to deactivate the random MAC address but nothing seems changed. Anyone experienced the same issue or can suggest a fix?

Did you try running the built in Wi-Fi diagnostics? Hold down  while clicking the Wi-Fi menu in the menu bar to see the advanced stuff, and select the diags command that appears.

tried, I have the repo, need to look inside the created zip. I've the suspect the random mac address is the problem, my fritz 7510 will recognize the mac with a different name/ip every time.

Do you have the same problem when connecting to a different wireless network? What is the "created zip" you mention? When asked for more information or to try something, please use the EDIT button and add the information or the outcome of what you've tried to your main post. This will result in your question becoming more and more complete, which will, in turn, increase the chances you'll get good answers.

Run a simple wireless diagnostic:

Option + click Wi-Fi symbol on toolbar
Open Wireless Diagnostics
Continue

Apparently the diagnostics tool reconfigures the Wi-Fi settings and this will completely fix the issue.


I was experiencing the same issue but it wasn't like daily but after updating to 15.1 I don't see the same issue anymore.
If you haven't updated to the latest update maybe you should.

I'm on 15.0.1 (24A348)

I'm on version 15.1 (24B83)
